# Some form inputs are being cleared when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

Im using cypress to automate a form. I have added all inputs but when I click 'Boook' button or any button inside form, some input fields gets cleared. I am unable to submit this form because of this issue.Is there any solution to it?

```
cy.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'specific-translator')]/div[2]/input").first().type('hira@translator.dt',{force: true})
cy.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Klicka')]").first().click()
cy.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'specific-translator')]/div[2]/input").first().should('have.value','hira@translator.dt')
cy.pause(10)
cy.xpath("//span[text()=' Boka ']").first().click()
```

[translator feild is cleared after click[image: ][1]]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works on your side:

```
    cy.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'specific-translator')]/div[2]/input").first().type('hira@translator.dt',{force: true}).as('inputVal')
    cy.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Klicka')]").first().click()
    cy.get('@inputVal').invoke('val').then((text)=>
    {
        expect(text).to.equals('hira@translator.dt')
    })
    cy.pause(10)
    cy.xpath("//span[text()=' Boka ']").first().click()
```